# Asyncronous background processing with Flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-asyncio

I have a process that I want to call via http endpoint that will trigger off async processes (almost batch like).

without server functionality, My code:

```
async def run(cmd):
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        cmd,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)

    stdout, stderr = await proc.communicate()

    print(f'[{cmd!r} exited with {proc.returncode}]')
    if stdout:
        if proc.returncode == 0:
            print(f'[stdout]\n{Fore.GREEN}{stdout.decode()}{Style.RESET_ALL}!')
        else:
            print(f'[stdout]\n{Fore.RED}{stdout.decode()}{Style.RESET_ALL}!')
    if stderr:
        print(f'[stderr]\n{Fore.RED}{stderr.decode()}{Style.RESET_ALL}!')
```

then I can call the subprocess via:

```
async def abar():
    await asyncio.gather(
        run('python3 --version') #literally ANY long process
       #that i need to call
    )
```

from there I Can do:

> asyncio.run(abar())

and my application runs successfully. My Goal was the put the `asyncio.run` part behind a flask endpoint:

```
@app.route("/batch")
def e2e():
    asyncio.run(abar())
    return 'OK'
```

however, doing so seems to throw Errors:

> Cannot add child handler, the child watcher does not have a loop attached

what would be the best way to trigger asynchronous subprocess calls via some http endpoint?

I tried using `subprocess.call`, but that does not seem to be async...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using `subprocess.Popen`

instead of

```
async def abar():
    await asyncio.gather(
        run('python3 --version') #literally ANY long process
       #that i need to call
    )
```

I did:

```
async def abar():
   Popen(['pyton3', '--version']) # or any long process
```

and in the actual flask route:

```
@app.route("/batch")
    def e2e():
       abar()
```